# How to remove last value in an from an object in php

Tags: php

I am trying to make a more secure login process for my new website, I am using the MVC model in PHP, so this is a snippet of the code

```
$userData = $app->UserDetails($user_id); 
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
             array_pop($userData);
             $_SESSION['userData'] = $userData;
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id; // Set Session
```

$app is actually an object that I created and here is the error that occurs when I try to login, can anyone help me please

```
Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\ibuy_e-commerce\accounts\index.php
```

Comment: the issue is in the error its an object not an array. If `array_pop` is an attempt to remove say `$userData->x`, then just do `unset($userData->x)`, or implement into `UserDetails($user_id, ['a', 'b', 'c'])` to return only them fields

Comment: An object doesn't have a "last value", it has named properties, and methods. You'll need to clarify what you're actually trying to do: what does the object look like, and what do you want it to look like after the line that's failing.